# CMS template creation and jQuery integration

Tags: jquery, content-management-system

First off I should say that I don't have any experience in working with a CMS.

I have 2 general questions about CMS:

- How easy is it to create a template?  I have strong CSS/XHTML skills, is creating a template as easy as writing the markup or does it have to be done in a very rigid way?
- How is jQuery support in CMS systems?  I like what you can do with jQuery and would like to incorporate it into the next couple of sites that I will do.

**EDIT:**

So far answers are asking which CMS, I don't have any in mind.  Any suggestions welcome, open source and non .NET preferable.

Comment: What CMS? The ease of front-end development varies wildly between CMSes.

Comment: @Tom, sorry I should have said.  I'm open to suggestions, open source and not .NET is the only criteria really.  I have LAMP webspace with Drupal, Joomla, Mambo, PHP-Nuke etc. ready to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1:

It is quite easy. You just create your mark up with XHTML/CSS as you've always done. The point is that you have to leave placeholders/holes/(divs with nothing in them)/li's to store dynamic content.

Remember you'll still have to choose a CMS framework from the variety out there. I find Wordpress great.

Question 2:

Just like you've always done in your previous sites. Just include the jQuery library on all templates and write you jQuery script as you go.

I'll be back with more info.

UPDATE:

For Wordpress templating check this:

- [Designing for WordPress: Complete Series & Downloads](http://css-tricks.com/designing-for-wordpress-complete-series-downloads/)

For jQuery integration:

- [Using jQuery with WordPress](http://themocracy.com/2009/04/using-jquery-with-wordpress/)
- [Using jQuery in your WordPress theme](http://ericdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/02/08/using-jquery-in-your-wordpress-theme/)
- [Another one](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)
- [5 tips for using jQuery with Wordpress](http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)

I hope it helps you get started. It helped me.

UPDATE:

I don't know why the links are not working.

- Another one (http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)
- 5 for using jQuery with Wordpress (http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/)

Comment: Like in wordpress, there are templates for pages, blog, archieves... So if you designate a page to inherit a particular template you should have designed a template so your page looks in a particular way when you choose one of those.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean jQuery integration in the front-end, you should be able to add any jQuery logic you want to the front-end templates by just including jQuery and your JavaScript. It sounds like you've got a hammer and now you're looking for a nail. I don't really see why CMS-driven sites would be any different for jQuery/ JavaScript logic.

Answer (score 0):

> How easy is it to create a template? I have strong CSS/XHTML skills, is creating a template as easy as writing the markup or does it have to be done in a very rigid way?

This totally depends on the CMS. Some CMS's use plain HTML with some Template or Scripting language variables in it. That will be pretty straightforward to get into. Other CMS's use complex XML/XSLT-based templating languages that take some time to learn. I found [Genshi](http://genshi.edgewall.org/) (used as a template engine in the popular [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) project management system) very complex for example.

jQuery support in the front-end is usually down to the template used, except if the CMS comes with pre-built front-end controls that require a Javascript framework like jQuery or Prototype.

Bottom line: It really depends which CMS we are talking about.

Comment: Would you recommend just picking a CMS and going with it?

Comment: @Fermin basically yes. What CMS makes sense for you really depends on what you want to do. Are you looking to improve your skills in general? Do you want to start building web sites for a living, or just one for yourself? Do you want to start this as a hobby? Do you speak any server-side languages like PHP or ASP?

Comment: Improve skills in general but have a project in mind (a small one for a relative).  I have some experience with PHP, not used ASP but I'm quick to pick up languages, I mostly work with .NET server side but my hosting is LAMP.